# Plot number of people (observations) in a data set?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to use a barplot to display the number of male and female participants for a program in the month of July. However, I keep getting a percentage instead. I know there's something wrong with my code but I'm not sure what.

```
july_all%>%
  filter(month == 0)%>%
  group_by(sex)%>%
  summarize(id=round(100*n()/nrow(july_all)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x =sex,y =id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat ="identity") + 
  labs(y ="Number of participants")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any data, but I'm guessing the following is a reasonable approximation:

```r
set.seed(1)

july_all <- data.frame(sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 500, TRUE), month = 0)
```

Now, running your code, we get:

```r
july_all %>%
  filter(month == 0) %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(id = round(100*n()/nrow(july_all))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =sex, y = id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat ="identity") + 
  labs(y ="Number of participants")
```

[image]

Which shows percentages. Why? Because that's what you have calculated with `summarize(id = round(100*n()/nrow(july_all)))` . Here, `id` is the percentage of each sex present in the data.

If you want raw counts, your code can be much simpler, since `geom_bar` plots counts by default, so you need only do:

```r
july_all %>%
  filter(month == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  labs(y ="Number of participants")
```

[image]

And you'll see we have the raw counts plotted.